# How to plot a graph of f(x) vs g(x)? Not just f(g(x))

Tags: plotting, functions

I have 3 functions:
$$
\left(v(\text{k$\_$})=\frac{\partial \omega (k)}{\partial k}\right)\\
\left(g(\text{k$\_$})=\frac{a n}{\pi  | v(k)| }\right)\\ \left(\omega (\text{k$\_$})=\sqrt{\frac{2 (f (1-\cos (2 a k))+\kappa  (1-\cos (a k)))}{m}}\right)
$$

Now, I want to plot $g(\omega)$ instead of $g(k)$. Is there a simple way to do it?

That is, I don't want $g(\omega(k))$. I want $g(k)$ plotted against each $\omega(k)$ corresponding to each $k$.

Here are the plots for $\omega(k)$:
[image: omega(k)]

And $g(k)$:

[image: g(k)]\

And here's `ParametricPlot[{ ω[k], g[k]}, {k, 0, x}]`:

[image: parametric plot]

It doesn't produce what I want. My guess is that's because $\omega$ is not 1-to-1?

Here's the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ω[k_] = 
  Sqrt[2/m (κ (1 - Cos[k a]) + f (1 - Cos[2 k a]))];
v[k_] = D[ω[k], k];
g[k_] = n a/π 1/Abs[v[k]];
x = π/a;
κ = 3;
f = 5;
m = 10;
a = 0.1;
Plot[ω[k], {k, -3 x, 3 x}, 
 Ticks -> {{-3 x, -x, 0, x, 3 x}, Automatic}]
Plot[ω[k]/k, {k, -3 x, 3 x}, 
 Ticks -> {{-3 x, -x, 0, x, 3 x}, Automatic}]
Plot[v[k], {k, -3 x, 3 x}, Ticks -> {{-3 x, -x, 0, x, 3 x}, Automatic}]
n = 10;
Plot[g[k], {k, 0, x}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 17.21364599572073, x}, {20, 40, 60}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, 60}}]
ParametricPlot[{ ω[k], g[k]}, {k, 0, x}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, MaxValue[ω[k], k]}, {0, 10}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, Round[ω[x], 0.001], 
    Round[MaxValue[ω[k], k], 0.001]}, Automatic}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

Comment: `ParametricPlot`

Comment: Yeah, my problem is that it does a mess since omega is not one-to-one (last graph). Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Look up `AspectRatio`

Comment: Please post your copy and paste-able code (InputForm) for the function definitions. Include the parameter values used for the plots.

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code instead of LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

κ = 3;
f = 5;
m = 10;
a = 1/10;
x = π/a;
n = 10;
ω[k_] = Sqrt[2/m (κ (1 - Cos[k a]) + f (1 - Cos[2 k a]))] // 
  Simplify;

v[k_] = D[ω[k], k];

g[k_] = n a/π 1/Abs[v[k]];

ωmax = MaxValue[{ω[k], 0 < k < x}, k] // Simplify

(* 23/(10 Sqrt[2]) *)

ParametricPlot[{ω[k], g[k]}, {k, 0, x},
 PlotRange -> {{0, ωmax}, {0, 10}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {HoldForm@ω[k], 
     HoldForm@g[k]}),
 FrameTicks -> {{0, Round[ω[x], 0.001], 
    Round[ωmax, 0.001]}, Automatic},
 Exclusions -> None,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{ω, g, k}, ColorData["Rainbow"][k]],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, x}},
   LegendLabel -> Style["k", 14]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can get g[w] directly in analytical form.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

\[Kappa] = 3;
f = 5;
m = 10;
a = 1/10;
x = \[Pi]/a;
n = 10;
\[Omega][k_] = 
   Sqrt[2/m (\[Kappa] (1 - Cos[k a]) + f (1 - Cos[2 k a]))];
v[k_] = D[\[Omega][k], k];
g[k_] = n a/\[Pi] 1/Abs[v[k]];
\[Omega]max = NMaxValue[\[Omega][k], k]

sol = Solve[{g[k] == gg, \[Omega][k] == ww, 0 < k}, gg, k, Reals, 
   Method -> Reduce];

{gw1[ww_], gw2[ww_], gw3[ww_]} = gg /. List @@ sol;

Plot[Evaluate[{gw1[ww], gw2[ww], gw3[ww]}], {ww, 0, \[Omega]max}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]

gw2[13/10]

(*   (100 (191 - 3 Sqrt[191]))/(1337 \[Pi])   *)
```

You can transform the Root expressions in gw1,gw2,gw3 to radical form, but attention, sometimes //ToRadicals does wrong.